# np.mean for rows with specific values across multiple columns

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I'm relatively new to Python and wasn't able to find an answer to my question.

Lets say I have saved a DataFrame into the variable movies. The DataFrame looks somewhat like this:

```
Genre1    Genre2   Genre3          sales
Fantasy   Drama    Romance         5
Action    Fantasy  Comedy          3
Comedy    Drama    ScienceFiction  4
Drama     Romance  Action          8
```

What I wanna do is get the average sales for every unique Genre that appears in any of the columns Genre1, Genre2 or Genre3.
I've tried a few different things. What I have right now is:

```
for x in pd.unique(movies[['Genre1','Genre2','Genre3']].values.ravel()):
mean_genre = np.mean(movies['sales']) 
print(x, mean_genre)
```

What I get as a result is:

```
Fantasy  5.0
Drama  5.0
Romance 5.0
Action  5.0
Comedy  5.0
ScienceFiction 5.0
```

So it does get me the unique Genres across the three columns but it calculates the average for the whole column sales. How do I get it to calculate the average sales for every unique Genre that appears in any of the three columns Genre1, Genre2 and Genre3? e.g. for the Genre 'Fantasy' it should use row 1 and 2 to calculate the average sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an even shorter version:

```
allGenre=pd.unique(movies[['Genre1','Genre2','Genre3']].values.ravel())
for genre in allGenre:
    print("%s : %f") % (genre,movies[movies.isin([genre]).any(1)].sales.mean())
```

Comment: Indeed I might prefer your solution to mine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is what you want to achieve but this should look for the sale value for each genre (each time it is encountered) :

```
all_genres = pd.unique(movies[['Genre1','Genre2','Genre3']].values.ravel())
dff = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Nb_sales', 'Nb_view'],
                   index=all_genres, data=0)

for col in ['Genre1', 'Genre2', 'Genre3']:
    for genre, value in zip(movies[col].values, movies['sales'].values):
        dff.loc[(genre, 'Nb_sales')] += value
        dff.loc[(genre, 'Nb_view')] += 1
```

Then you can compute the mean value :

```
>>> dff['Mean'] = dff.Nb_sales / dff.Nb_view
>>> dff
                Nb_sales  Nb_view      Mean
Romance               13        2  6.500000
Comedy                 7        2  3.500000
ScienceFiction         4        1  4.000000
Fantasy                8        2  4.000000
Drama                 17        3  5.666667
Action                11        2  5.500000
```

More compact solutions could be :

```
all_genres = pd.unique(movies[['Genre1','Genre2','Genre3']].values.ravel())

mean_series = pd.Series(index=all_genres)
for genre in all_genres:
    mean_series[genre] = movies.sales.loc[movies.eval(
        'Genre1 == "{0}" or Genre2 == "{0}" or Genre3 == "{0}"'
        .format(genre)).values].mean()

# Or in one (long) line:
mean_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Genre'], data=all_genres)
mean_df['mean'] = mean_df.Genre.apply(
    lambda x: movies.sales.loc[movies.eval(
        'Genre1 == "{0}" or Genre2 == "{0}" or Genre3 == "{0}"'
        .format(x)).values].mean())
```

Where they both will print your results:

```
>>> print(mean_series)
Fantasy           4.000000
Drama             5.666667
(....)
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!